# Convergence of functions in $L^2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

> Suppose $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and let $c>0$.  Define $f_c(x)$ to be $f(x)$ when $|x|\leq c$ and $0$ when $|x|>c$. Show that $$\lim_{c\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_c(x)e^{-ixy}dx$$  exists, where the limit is in the $L^2$ sense.

We know by the dominated convergence theorem that $\|f_c-f\|_2\rightarrow 0$ as $c\rightarrow\infty$. Might that help to show that this limit exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c_n$ be any sequence that tends  to $\infty$. Since the sequence $(f_{c_n}) $ converges in   $L^2$, it is Cauchy in $L^2$.  By Parseval's identity, the sequence $(\widehat{f_{c_n}})$ is Cauchy in $L^2$ as well:
$$\|\widehat{f_{c_n}}-\widehat{f_{c_m}}\| = \|f_{c_n}-f_{c_m}\|$$
(maybe with some constant multiple, depending on the Fourier transform convention.) 
Hence, the sequence $(\widehat{f_{c_n}})$ converges in $L^2$.

If the limit of $\widehat{f_c}$ exists along every  sequence $c_n$ as above, 
then   $\lim_{c\to\infty} \widehat{f_c}$ also exists. This is a general fact about convergence, which is easy to prove by contrapositive: if $\widehat{f_c}$ fail to have a limit, there is a sequence $c_n$ which exhibits this failure.